# Tengo una serie de datos cada 5 minutos, quiero sacar el promedio por hora y por día

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tengo una serie de datos por un mes que se repiten cada 5 minutos, quiero sacar el promedio por hora y luego por día. Estoy tratando de hacerlo en Python, pero apenas estoy iniciando en la programación. Lo tengo en un excel, intente hacer ub ciclo pero no encontré como medir la los pasos, son 12 por hora y 288 por día.

```
# Libraries to help with reading and manipulating data
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Libraries to help with data visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Command to tell Python to actually display the graphs
%matplotlib inline

df=pd.read_excel("Profile.xlsx","amCharts", index_col="Date/Time")
       
    Date/Time             MWh
    2023-04-01 00:00    12.498
    2023-04-01 00:05    12.454
    2023-04-01 00:10    12.367
    2023-04-01 00:15    12.343
    2023-04-01 00:20    12.454
    
df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'], infer_datetime_format=True)

promedio = df.groupby([df.index.hour, df.index.month])['MWh'].mean()
```

Intente hacer conversión de tiempo pero me marco error y después no me deja avanzar para agrupar y sacar promedio horario y por día.

Me marca el siguiente error:

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3802, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>    3801 try:
> -> 3802     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
>    3803 except KeyError as err:
>
> KeyError: 'Date/Time'
> ```

Agradecería su ayuda

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega algunas filas de tu `dataset` como texto, no como imagen y el mínimo código necesario para reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo edité a ver si está mejor, apenas estoy iniciando

Comment: El nombre de la columna es exactamente "Date/Time" sin ningún espacio adicional alrededor?